# Wordpress Advanced Custom Field select result display twice?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Advanced Custom Field in Wordpress. I use the_field('brand') to display the value of custom field, in my case, it is called brand. However, when I use select field type, the result displayed twice. Like: 
nike:NIKE
adidas:ADIDAS

I assume one is label, one is value? how can I only show the value in frontend?
This is my code

Thank you, Akshay. But it still show both label and value. below is my code:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'kosher',
        $current_query['taxonomy'] => $taxonomy_term
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query -> have_posts() ) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>   
    <?php 
        $values = get_field('brand');
    ?>
        <p><b><?php print_r($values); ?></b> &nbsp;<?php the_field('key'); ?> &nbsp;<?php the_title(); ?> &nbsp;<?php the_field( 'description' ); ?> </p>
        <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <p>There are no posts or pages here</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Below is the edited code, but still receive undefined error:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'kosher',
        $current_query['taxonomy'] => $taxonomy_term
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query -> have_posts() ) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>   
    <?php 
        $field = get_field_object('brand');
        $value = get_field('brand');
        $label = $field['choices'][ $value ];
    ?>
        <p><b><?php print_r($label); ?></b> &nbsp;<?php the_field('key'); ?> &nbsp;<?php the_title(); ?> &nbsp;<?php the_field( 'description' ); ?> </p>
        <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <p>There are no posts or pages here</p>
```

I var_dump the object:

```
$field = get_field_object('brand');
var_dump($field);
```

And below is what I have got, the value is herman jansen: HERMAN JANSEN, that's what showed up on my front end every time, what code should I use to only show "HERMAN JANSEN"?

```
array(17) { 
["key"]=> string(19) "field_533221abdb3be" 
["label"]=> string(5) "Brand" 
["name"]=> string(5) "brand" 
["_name"]=> string(5) "brand" 
["type"]=> string(6) "select" 
["order_no"]=> int(3) 
["instructions"]=> string(0) "" 
["required"]=> int(0) 
["id"]=> string(15) "acf-field-brand" 
["class"]=> string(6) "select" 
["conditional_logic"]=> array(3) { 
    ["status"]=> int(0) 
    ["rules"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> array(2) { 
            ["field"]=> string(4) "null"
             ["operator"]=> string(2) "==" } } 
        ["allorany"]=> string(3) "all" } 
["choices"]=> array(4) { 
    ["BOLS"]=> string(4) "BOLS" 
    ["HERMAN JANSEN"]=> string(13) "HERMAN JANSEN" 
    ["WARNICKS"]=> string(9) "WARNICK'S" 
    ["CARLTON BLACK"]=> string(13) "CARLTON BLACK" } 
["default_value"]=> string(0) "" 
["allow_null"]=> int(0) 
["multiple"]=> int(0) 
["field_group"]=> int(140) 
["value"]=> string(28) "herman jansen: HERMAN JANSEN" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get_field` to get your field.

```
$variable = get_field('brand');
print_r($variable);
```

Print `$variable` that way you can see what result will come.

For Select Field Type [See Documents](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/select/).

From Document, Use this:-

```
$field = get_field_object('brand');
$value = get_field('brand');
$label = $field['choices'][ $value ];
```

Hi,

I have noticed strange thing in ACF.

You need to specify select choices in ACF field settings like this:-

```
`red : Red` instead of `red: Red`
```

You might need to add space before `:`.

Check your options in ACF settings.

This will surely work.

Comment: Thank you, Akshay. But it still show both label and value. I just added my code into my question.

Comment: `print_r` is use for printing array. Just see what's in the `$variable`. May be `$variable` is an array.

Comment: Have you seen link that i have added in my answer ? Look at once. You will understand.

Comment: Hi, Akshay: I read that document many times. it just doesn't make sense to me.All I have got was Undefined index error on $label = $field['choices'][ $value ];

Comment: Thank you, Akshay. it is exactly what I wrote in my code, and it showed me undefined index error. I have posted my code.

Comment: Hi, Akshay: I think I am getting closer, I var_dump the object, and find out the value is herman jansen: HERMAN JANSEN. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Hey, Akshay! It works! I don't know how. I went back and deleted the "brand" field, and recreated a "manufacture" field. then just copy&paste everything in there. then it works! really wield. Thank you very much! man, appreciate it.